# Typescript constraint validation API event type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

in a function passed to `onBlur` I need to access the `validity` object and the `checkValidity` function from `event.target` but I can't find a suitable type. Here's my code:

```
function validateOnBlur(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
  const { validity } = event.target; 

  // displays "Property 'validity' does not exist on type 'FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>' "
}
```

Does anyone have an idea on which type should `event` be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validity property comes from `event.target`, so you need to do it like this:

```
const { validity } = event.target;
```

Edit:
This should work fine:

`React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> should be OK.